# Firebase Storage and Swift - download task handling

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a download task to get the video file. I checked the documentation about the download task but I don't see anything about handling the existing files.

Does the download task checks the existing file, then checks if it need to be resumed or leaves it alone?

If the download task fails in the middle of downloading, will the incomplete file still there?

If it don't overwrite the file, how do I compare the files in local and remote (file size? or MD5) to verify that I don't need to download the file?

Scenario - I have AppDelegateManager to download all of the videos beforehand. I don't want to download the videos each time the app is opened and wasn't sure if the videos were overwritten or not.

```
func getVideo(fileName : String, localUrl : URL, completion : @escaping (_ success : Bool) -> Void) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let pathReference = storage.reference(withPath: FirebaseDirectoryNames.videos.rawValue + "/" + fileName)
    
    let downloadTask = pathReference.write(toFile: localUrl) { url, error in
      if let error = error {
        os_log("error : ", log: self.tag, type: .debug, error.localizedDescription)
        completion(false)
      } else {
        completion(true)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code would redownload and overwrite your file. You could just change the function to 1st look for the local file and if it fails/doesn't exist, then download from Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying this approach - I was thinking about edge cases like if it is downloading then stopped at 50%, will the incomplete file be there? I'll see if I can add some kind of catching error to redownload the file. Thanks!

Comment: The function will only return completion(true) if it 100% downloads. if If it fails, it should return completion(false). You can handle it in your completion handler. Cheers